# Way to deep copy flatbuffer object

Tags: java, deep-copy, flatbuffers

I represented my data with flatbuffer. Currently I had a problem that I am dividing a big collection of objects in flatbuffer into some small pieces.

The straight forward way would be to create a flatbuffer builder for each piece, and then write the object into that builder. But when object is a bit complex, it is a quite tedious work to copy the data struct by struct.

Since the flatbuffer stores relative offsets, theoritically I think it is possible to simply copy the byte buffer to do copying the object into another flatbuffer instance. Is there already something to deep copy it available ? I am using java now. Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated than you think, since a table and its children are not neccessarily contiguous in memory, and may share vtables with other tables, etc.

The easiest way is to use nested FlatBuffers (stick a child object in a byte vector), since it is then trivially copyable.

There is a deep copy function using reflection in C++, but it is slow, requires a binary schema file, and has not been ported to Java yet. The new "mini reflection" tables would be suitable for deep copy, but also are C++ only so far.